# Database Project VS 2012 Skip Publishing Security

Tags: database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, publishing, database-project

I get no errors when publishing, however my colleague is receiving an error when publishing. The error seems to be when executing a "Create Login [pjames] With...". The first line in the error says:

> (47,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15247, Level 16,
>   State 1, Line 1 User does not have permission to perform this action.

When we publish we don't want to publish scripts in the Security folder, which seems to be scripts for creating log ins. How do I leverage the DB project to avoid publishing things from the Security Folder?

Answer (score 3):

If you double click the publish profile, click advanced, and in the ignore tab you may check off exclude log ins.

[image]